# Can't list documents in mongodb collection using MongoClient in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can connect to my database from node.js using the MongoClient. I amb able to write, update and remove docs from a collection. But I am not able to retrieve data from it. This is my code:

```
var mongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoDbObj;

mongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/trendoa', function(err, db){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    global.db = db;
};

var col = global.db.collection('twitter_accounts_mon');

// create
var doc1 = {'hola':'sushi'};
col.insert(doc1, function(err, result) {
  callback(err);
});

// update
col.update({hola:'jordi'}, {$set:{hola:'joan'}}, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});

// delete
col.remove({hola:'jordi'}, function(err, result) {
  callback(err);
});

// read
col.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

What I'm trying to do in the last lines of code is to get all the documents using find() but it doesn't return any results.

Through the mongo shell, using this command I get data on screen:

```
db.twitter_accounts_mon.find()
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Try to move your code in database callback. After global.db=db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the nodejs callbacks must nest, ie only search the collection once the db is open

```
mongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/trendoa', function(err, db){
    var col = db.collection('twitter_accounts_mon');
    coll.find({}, function(err, cursor) {
        cursor.toArray(function(err, data) {
            // process the data array
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MongoDB [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) on the Node.js driver, the **find** method does not execute the actual query, it builds an instance of a **cursor** that you then use to retrieve data. thus, you need to handle the result of the query.

```
var entireCollectionArray = col.find().toArray(function(err, items) {});

entireCollectionArray.forEach(function (element) {
     console.log(element);
});
```